Lattice Constant Optimization for Janus Monolayers
How can I optimize the lattice constant for a Janus monolayer material like FeBrCl using VASP, ensuring accuracy in capturing its unique structural properties and potential symmetry breaking? Could you also explain the key steps and considerations for achieving convergence in this process?

Could you maybe expand on what you have done/already know?

@joerivan I have created a monolayer of FeBrCl with a structure similar to MoS₂ (hexagonal structure). Since the material has a Janus structure, I understand that before investigating its properties, such as electronic structure and density of states (DOS), it is essential to first optimize the crystal structure and determine the optimized lattice parameters. I would like to know how to perform lattice optimization in VASP.

You have to perform a relaxation. The symmetries should be lowered because of the distinct halides that are bound to the iron ion, but you kind of need to know or assume whether the halides will align along z or not. Depending on that you should impose some constraints. Furthermore your material will be magnetic, so you should also consider this in your relaxation step.

@franz thank you for your answer could you clarify what do you mean by imposing some constraints?

You can for example impose the constraint, that your halide atoms align along z, meaning your monolayer is in the hexagonal phase, not in the 1T phase. This is implicitly done by how you place the atoms in the card ATOMIC_POSITIONS. Furthermore I suggest you to use the keyword cell_dofree    = '2Dxy'keyword in the &CELL card, so that your vacuum distance is not changed.

@franz VASP does not have these 'cards'. If you want to enforce some constraints in VASP you can look at selective dynamics in which you specify in directions that atoms are allowed to move in (this is inside the POSCAR). The ISIF tag in the INCAR is also used to constrain the structure optimization

@joerivan thanks for correcting me. I saw the Quantum Espresso tag in the question.and must have missed that the question is actually VASP related.
